# How to Print my Object name in Python

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

So I have a problem with this code:

```
class Cliente:
    def __init__(self,nome,telefone):
        self.nome = nome;
        self.telefone = telefone;

class Conta:
    def __init__(self,clientes,numero,saldo=0):
        self.saldo = saldo
        self.numero = numero
        self.clientes = clientes
    def resumo(self):
        print('Cliente: {0:s} CC Numero: {1:s} Saldo: {2:10.2f}'.format(self.clientes.nome, self.numero, self.saldo))
    def saque(self,valor):
        if self.saldo >= valor:
            self.saldo -= valor
    def deposito(self,valor):
        self.saldo += valor
```

When I go to test my class:

```
from tatu import Cliente
from tatu import Conta

joao = Cliente('Joao da Silva','666-6666')
maria = Cliente('Maria da Penha','234-5678')
conta1 = Conta(joao,'0138',1500)
conta1.deposito(800)
conta1.saque(1300)
conta2 = Conta([joao,maria],'0139',1000)
conta2.deposito(1000)
conta1.resumo()
conta2.resumo()
```

My second account don't print and I have this error:

```
print('Cliente: {0:s} CC Numero: {1:s} Saldo: {2:10.2f}'.format(self.clientes.nome, self.numero, self.saldo))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'nome'
```

Comment: Your second account is a **list** of `Cliente` objects, not a single object.

Comment: Yes, I want an account with two clients, how to declare it ?

Comment: @JhonatanMark Do you want an account with two clients, or an account with multiple clients?  If it's just two then you can have `self.client1 = client1; self.client2 = client2`.  If you want multiple then you should be passing in a list.  If you want to get all names for every client in a list then you can use list comprehensions or `map`: `[client.nome for client in self.clientes]` or `map(lambda client: client.nome, self.clientes)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing types; sometimes your `clientes` is *one* `Cliente` instance, sometimes it is a list.

Always make it a list instead, and then *loop* over that list:

```
# account with just one client
conta1 = Conta([joao],'0138',1500)
# account with two clients
conta2 = Conta([joao,maria],'0139',1000)
```

and now that it is always a list, use a loop:

```
def resumo(self):
    for client in self.clientes:
        print('Cliente: {0:s} CC Numero: {1:s} Saldo: {2:10.2f}'.format(client.nome, self.numero, self.saldo))
```

or perhaps split out the client names list and print account number and saldo separately:

```
def resumo(self):
    for client in self.clientes:
        print('Cliente: {0:s}'.format(client.nome))
    print('CC Numero: {1:s} Saldo: {2:10.2f}'.format(self.numero, self.saldo))
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.clientes` is not an instance of Cliente, it is a list of instances. The list itself does not have the nome property, only the instances do. You would need to iterate through.